# Unit tests grouping "Project, NameSpace, Class" being demolished by dots from TestCase.TestName

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, nunit, test-explorer

I do use Test-Explorer and find comfortable the view where unit tests are grouped by "Project, NameSpace, Class". It also does work well with parameterized tests, where I can also use a `TestName` for better labeling/description.
However dots in the `TestName` do demolish the structured view:

[image]

I don't know whether it is "feature" of Visual Studio or NUnit, but the question is:

Is there any possibility to remain the dots(may be using some escape chars syntax) and "Project, NameSpace, Class" grouping?

```
[TestFixture]
public class ClassToTest_Fixture
{
    [TestCase("no dots data input", TestName = nameof(string.Replace) + " no") ]
    [TestCase("no dots data input", TestName = nameof(string.Replace) + " dots")]
    [TestCase("no dots data input", TestName = nameof(string.Replace) + " data input")]
    [TestCase("dots data input :( ", TestName = nameof(string.Replace) + "  dots.data input")]
    [TestCase("dots data input :( ", TestName = nameof(string.Replace) + "  dots.data.input")]
    public void TestMethod(object someData)
    {  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that this will be an answer, which only tells you why the bad thing happens. :-)

Short solution: don't set a test name with dots in it!

Visual Studio is completely responsible for the appearance of the display, using information provided by the NUnit 3 Test Adapter. That information is basically full name of the method and a display name for the test case itself. When you use the `TestName` property with your attribute, you change that display name but nothing else.

What's more, the NUnit adapter doesn't know what grouping you have asked Visual Studio to use. So it can't react to that by supplying a modified test name. This is, of course, just the normal sort of isolation and separation of functionality one wants between a host and an extension.

Apparently, Visual Studio Test Explorer is interpreting the dots in your test name in some way. That's probably a bug (I think, anyway) and you could ask them to fix it. In the short term, I would just stop using dots. :-)

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm afraid, that it's the only way to stop using dots. :( As a workaround I will go with commas (I have hoped to go with arabic point but there are a problems with dot at the end of words because of right to left writing)